# Android: How to Access a non-Activity Xml onClick attribute method in an Activity Class

Tags: java, android, customdialog

I have a `CustomDialog` on which I use hundreds of `TextViews` with `onClick` attributes, Now I want to access these `onClick` methods in an `Activity class`. As this `CustomDialog` is inflated from the `Activity` class on which I want to access the `onClick` methods, So when I create methods for that `onClick` like

```
public void playerEdit(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Obviously it throws an `Exception` which is

```
 Could not find a method playeEdit(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'p1'
```

It means I tried to fetch it in a non-accessible Class,

My Question is how can I access it in that `Activity Class`?

How do I handle this `Exception`?
Many Many Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a typo in your xml file. Method name is "playeEdit" instead of "playerEdit"

Comment: its mistakenly written here, I have playerEdit both in xml and in class,

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that when you are constructing your AlertDialog, you are doing it in a similar fashion:

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
```

(Posting entire code helps )

You are getting the exception because the activity in which the onClick handler in your xml is looking inside (and where your xml is inflated into) is in this themed activity, not the original activity!

You will need to extend the ContextThemeWrapper class, pass that into the builder, and implement your click handler like so:

```
public static class MyContextThemeWrapper extends ContextThemeWrapper
{

    public MyContextThemeWrapper() {
        super();
    }

    public MyContextThemeWrapper(Context base, int themeres) {
        super(base, themeres);
    }

    public void playerEdit(View view)
    {
        // Do stuff when clicked
    }

}
```

And as mentioned, you will pass your class into your builder like so:

```
MyContextThemeWrapper themedContext = new MyContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
```

This does work... I tested it!